# How do I add media Queries into Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to add media jquery's into your jquery code?

I need to reduce "slideWidth: 83," when my screen hits a size of 800px;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slider4').bxSlider({
    slideWidth: 83,
    minSlides: 2,
    maxSlides: 9,
    moveSlides: 1,
    slideMargin: 15
  });
});
```

Answer (score 9):

Media queries are supported in js via `window.matchMedia`

This allows you to create something like

```
var isPortrait = window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)");
if (isPortrait.matches){
    // Screen is portrait
}
```

or

```
var smallScreen = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 480px)");
if (smallScreen.matches){
    // Screen is less than 480px
}
```

Support is good within modern browsers and there is a [polyfill](https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/) available as well but it doesn't support resizing out of the box.

More info –
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia

Answer (score 6):

No, but you can measure the *current* width of the window and configure your code based on that:

```
if ($(window).width()<768) {
   // do whatever
}
```

If you need it to be responsive, tie your code to the `window.onresize` event as well:

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    if ($(window).width()<768) {
        // do whatever
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant explicitly have media queries, but you can check the window width with this little code :

```
function viewport() {
    var e = window, a = 'inner';
    if (!('innerWidth' in window )) {
        a = 'client';
        e = document.documentElement || document.body;
    }
    return { width : e[ a+'Width' ] , height : e[ a+'Height' ] };
}
```

I cant remember where I found this code so i can't give the credit...

Anyway, use the window resize event to check the width like that :

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if(viewport().width > x && viewport().width < y){
        //do something
    }
}).trigger('resize');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Paul Irish's **[MatchMedia.js polyfill](https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/)** to do Javascript media queries but it will not work in IE9 and earlier.  Still it's quite useful and you can conditionally handle IE with a less precise method (like `$(window).width()`).

- [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia)
- [Caniuse compatibility table](http://caniuse.com/matchmedia)