# Add media queries to offset scroll jQuery

Tags: jquery, scroll, media-queries, offset

I'm building a website with a navigation that jumps to anchors on a different page of the website. To compensate for the sticky header that's blocking the top part of the content I found this code snippet.

It works, but only on desktop. I would need to adjust the value for tablets and smartphones but since I have no idea of jQuery I'm completely clueless.

I would need one for min-width: 1025px, max-width: 1024px and max-width: 767px to adjust the height of the different header sizes.

How do I add those media queries into the snippet?

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var target = window.location.hash;

   // only try to scroll to offset if target has been set in location hash
       if (target != '') {
   var $target = jQuery(target);
jQuery('html, body').stop().animate({
  'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - 155
}, 900, 'swing', function() {
  window.location.hash = target - 40;
});
} 
});
```

Comment: hi, perhaps use `matchMedia` (or set display:none on an element to reomve it from view) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19930720/how-do-i-add-media-queries-into-jquery

Comment: hey, how would I implement this into the code above? I really have no idea of jQuery and I'm just thrown in at the deep end from a friend who wants a website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically read the height of your header.

Just replace your `155` with `parseInt($('.header').css('height'), 10)`. Obviously the `.header` is the selector in my example, if your header has an ID use `#YouIDName` if it has a class like in my example, use `.YourClassName`.

To see this example in action repeatedly click on `Run code snippet`.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var target = window.location.hash;
  
  
  // Only for test on Stack Overflow:
  target = '#myTarget'; // Force target for test
  $('.header').css('height', (Math.floor(Math.random() * 81) + 20) + 'px'); // Random height of header from 20 to 100
  $('.header').text('Current header height is ' + $('.header').css('height')); // Print header height
  // End rows for test //
  
  
  
  // only try to scroll to offset if target has been set in location hash
  if (target != '') {
    var $target = jQuery(target);
    jQuery('html, body').stop().animate({
      'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - parseInt($('.header').css('height'), 10) // Read the height of your header
    }, 900, 'swing', function() {
      window.location.hash = target - 40;
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.header {
  position: sticky;
  top:0;
  background-color:red;
  width:100%;
  height: 155px;
}

.content {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color:blue;
  width:100%;
  height: 600px;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color:yellow;
  width:100%;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="header">My header</div>
<div class="content">Random content</div>
<a id="myTarget" href="#myTarget">Target</a>
<div class="content">Random content</div>
```

**EDIT**

Anyway, not knowing the exact functioning of your layout, I add the solution with media queries via javascript.

The relevant part:

```
let headerHeight = 155;

if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 767px)")) {
  // Less then 767
  headerHeight = 50;
  console.log('header: 50 // max-width: 767px');
} else if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1024px)")) {
  // From 768 and 1024
  headerHeight = 100;
  console.log('header: 100 // max-width: 1024px');
} else {
  // Greater than 1024 (headerHeight = 155).
  //    You can remove this else.
  console.log('header: 155');
}
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var target = window.location.hash;


  // Only for test on Stack Overflow:
  target = '#myTarget'; // Force target for test
  
  // Force header height based on media query
  if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 767px)")) {
    $('.header').css('height', '50px');
  } else if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1024px)")) {
    $('.header').css('height', '100px');
  }
  // End rows for test //



  // only try to scroll to offset if target has been set in location hash
  if (target != '') {

    let headerHeight = 155;

    if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 767px)")) {
      // Less then 767
      headerHeight = 50;
      console.log('header: 50 // max-width: 767px');
    } else if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1024px)")) {
      // From 768 and 1024
      headerHeight = 100;
      console.log('header: 100 // max-width: 1024px');
    } else {
      // Greater than 1024 (headerHeight = 155).
      //    You can remove this else.
      console.log('header: 155');
    }


    var $target = jQuery(target);
    jQuery('html, body').stop().animate({
      'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - headerHeight
    }, 900, 'swing', function() {
      window.location.hash = target - 40;
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 155px;
}

.content {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="header">My header</div>
<div class="content">Random content</div>
<a id="myTarget" href="#myTarget">Target</a>
<div class="content">Random content</div>
```

Comment: Problem is, the header doesnt have a fixed height like in your example. Its height is based on the margins and sizes of the logo and navigation within

Comment: @Caro But I guess that at the time of loading the size of header has already been calculated, and the jump to the target happens only on loading, so it shouldn't be a problem. Does it change size while scrolling?

Comment: @Caro Answer updated.

Comment: ah thats what I was searching for! thank you